# ReactJS get parent virable from loop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from "items" array.
How do I achieve this?

They way I am trying to do:

Show code

This dosen't work, and I can't seem to find anything that answers my question..

```
render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
        return items.map(item => this.props.children);
    }
}


class text extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Senste indlæg</h2>
                <Posts>{item.title}</Posts>
                <div>Paginateion</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite unclear right now, can you rephrase it please?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense by whichever angle we try to look at it. Please elaborate by highlighting 'what your objective is', 'what have you tried so far' and 'what kind of help do you want from the community'.

Comment: Which code represents what ? What is not working ? Please elaborate and give us more details

Comment: So what I want to get, is the item.title in <Posts>

However, I dont know if this is the right way of doing it, or I am doing something wrong. Item.title does not give me the title from the object item.

See here:
return items.map(item => this.props.children);

Then I am trying to fetch the item object in my child

<Posts>{item.title}</Posts> <-- But this does not work? Maybe I am doing it wrong.